# Read/Parse a JSON file with list of dicts and dump into the database with pymongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, robo3t

I am having a JSON file with a list of json format dicts in it as shown below.

filename : test.json

content :

```
[
{
"name":"A",
"colour":"red",
"type":"active"
}
,
{
"name":"B",
"colour":"blue",
"type":"active"
}
]
```

I am having a separate python file as mytest.py.

Here I need to read or parse this test.json file and get the values in it and dump it into the mongodb. How to achieve/process such scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("CONNECTION URL")
db = client.DBName

with open('test.json') as fd:
    objs_list = json.load(fd)

for obj in objs_list:
    db.some_collection.insert_one(obj)
```

Also, don't forget to add the missing quotes in your JSON's objects keys.

Comment: missing quotes?

Comment: @Navi Your JSON is a list of dictionaries (AKA objects) and each one of them has the keys: name, colour and type, but those keys should be inside quotation marks as well. I.e.: ```[
{
"name":"A",
"colour":"red",
"type":"active"
}
,
{
"name":"B",
"colour":"blue",
"type":"active"
}
]```

Compare that JSON content to the one in your original post and note that your JSON is missing those quotation marks.

Comment: I have edited now

Comment: @Navi Great, now you should be able to get my code snippet to work :)

Comment: in the open(test.json). The test.json file is in a separate folder, whereas I gave along with the path like open(/project/jsons/test.json),. But it threw an error as no such directory.

Comment: @Navi '/project/jsons/test.json' is an absolute path, it will try to search it in the root of your machine. If your script is at '.' and the json is in './project/jsons/test.json' then you should use the following: 
```import os
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'project/jsons/test.json'):
    ...```